# Typeorm ROLLBACK cannot execute down() fn when migration run fails

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have the following migration file when I run `migration:generate`

```
    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`
            CREATE TABLE \`users3\` (
                \`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                \`username\` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)
            ) ENGINE = InnoDB
        `);
        await queryRunner.query(`
            CREATE TABLE \`users4\` (
                \`id\` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                \`value\` float(100) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (\`id\`)
            ) ENGINE = InnoDB
        `);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`
            DROP TABLE \`users4\`
        `);
        await queryRunner.query(`
            DROP TABLE \`users3\`
        `);
    }
```

It creates 2 tables `users3` & `users4`, when I run `migration:run` command, it gives the following:

```
error: Error: Incorrect column specifier for column 'value'
query: ROLLBACK
Error during migration run:
```

The issue for `value` column type in users4 table, so migration transaction gives ROLLBACK and no record has been added to migrations table but the issue here is that `users3` has been created so when I fix the issue in `users4` table and run the migration again it give

```
error: Error: Table 'users3' already exists
query: ROLLBACK
Error during migration run:
```

What I was expecting is that if the previous `migration:run` command failed then rollback is is executing the `down` function for `users3` which is

```
DROP TABLE \`users3\`
```

But this not happend, if `up()` didn't complete, then typeorm should revert all ran queries inside `up()` am I right?

this is because all migrations executed inside transaction so rolling back should revert all ran queries but this not happend unfortunately

Comment: Since users3 got created even when it was supposed to be rolled back, I would guess "all migrations executed inside transaction" is incorrect and they weren't in a transaction. Maybe check the docs here to see what transaction mode you're using? https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/migrations#transaction-modes

Comment: Hello @Cadence yes `users3` didn't rolled back, I have tried `--transaction each` but also not working